# Summation of a series of Positive Prime numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, prime-numbers

Is there a way to find the sum for a set of positive prime numbers (e.g., the first $25$ prime numbers) without just arbitrarily adding them up shorthand?

Comment: The set of the first 25 positive prime numbers would be a prime example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking whether there's an exact way of doing it (without just summing them up), no. Otherwise asymptotics give this:

$$P(n):=\sum_{i=1}^np_i \approx \frac{1}{2}n^2\ln(n),$$

the sum of the first $n$ primes. Note that if there is an exact formula for $P(n)$, then $p_n=P(n)-P(n-1)$ would give an exact formula for the $n$'th prime, which is highly unlikely.

[See here for more details.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeSums.html)

Comment: I have seen this formula of calculating a finite series of sums: (N(N+1)(2N+1))/6. What is this calculating? (Where N represents the number of numbers in the set)

Comment: That's the sum of consecutive squares, so 1+4+9+...+N^2.

Comment: @HillyBilly: This is completely different. You're thinking of $\sum_{k=1}^N k^2=N(N+1)(2N+1)/6$.

Comment: @Alex R.:Does that answer the question?

Comment: @HillyBilly: Sorry, I'm confused about what you're asking. Your question asks for the sum of primes in some set, and this answer shows asymptotic for calculating the sum of the first $n$ primes. I've added an edit.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If such a way existed, then we would have uncovered the mystery surrounding the prime numbers. So, there does not exist one that we know of. But there are good approximations, just like the other answer pointed out.